# nmap: easily Ping-Scan all addresses in my subnet

Tags: nmap

Is there an nmap line that will auto-detect my current IP address and subnet mask, and run a ping-scan on all? For example:

```
#> nmap -sP 0.0.0.0
```

Instead of manually:

```
#> nmap -sP 192.168.100.0/24
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think that there is a way with doing that with `nmap` alone, but you could script it:
Here is a quick and dirty solution:

```
#!/bin/bash

IP_AND_MASK=`ifconfig | grep "inet addr" | head -n1 | sed 's|.*addr:\([0-9\.]*\).*Mask:\([0-9\.]*\)|\1/\2|g'`
NETWORK=`ipcalc "$IP_AND_MASK" | grep "Network:" | sed 's|^Network:\s*\([0-9/\.]*\).*|\1|g'`
nmap -sP "$NETWORK"
```

You have to install `ipcalc` to make that solution work.

*hth*

Answer (score 2):

Mileage may vary, but this should work well in most circumstances...

```
nmap -sP `hostname -I | sed 's/[0-9]\+\s/0\/24 /g'`
```

Comment: It will work if my subnet is `/24` which for most homes it, but for some corporate environment isn't. Good tip though! I like it.

Answer (score -1):

This works, but then you still need to know your own subnet... saves copy-pasting the IP address though.

```
nmap -sP /24
```

Comment: On my system (OS X 10.10, nmap version 6.47) this doesn’t work for me. I get the following error: `::1/0 looks like an IPv6 target specification -- you have to use the -6 option.`.

Comment: Does not work on ubuntu 18.04. Need to specify the network ID address

Comment: try: nmap -sP 10.0.0.0/24 or maybe nmap -sP 192.168.0.0/24 works on macOS also